# How to install edx Insights for open edx installation in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: openedx

I have installed open edx in ubuntu the fiscus release. For students analytics i need edx insights
So,
1. Is it to be installed separately
2. It comes with open edx installation (If yes, Please share the port Number)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this (fairly recently updated) installation guide: https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/43385371/edX+Analytics+Installation

Comment: Followed and installed but its gives me page not found error while clicking on login button

Comment: Are you sure you have set the host names properly?